# How to set timezone using PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What should I do to get the current time stamp?

```
const query = "UPDATE gtt_ledger SET deleted_at = $1 WHERE id= $2 ";
let result = await client.query(query, [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , id]);
```

Comment: `const query = "UPDATE gtt_ledger SET deleted_at = current_timestamp WHERE id=$1";
let result = await client.query(query, [id]);`. Which is your RDBMS btw?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: Well, then the suggested code will work just fine. Maybe it would work in MySQL too, but I have no experience with it.